Angular .NET SPA- Reactive form doesn't clear values when user navigates away from page
My front end app architecture currently looks something like this:
<app root> <router-outlet></router-outlet> </app root>
The router-outlet starts with the default path pointing to a child component called IdRequestFormComponent:
export class IdRequestFormComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {


  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {

    //this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => {
    //  return false;
    //};
   
    this.IdRequestForm = this.fb.group({
        // controls initialized
    });

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
      this.IdRequestForm.reset();
    }

<form [formGroup]="IdRequestForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="mb-3 border border-light">
    <div class="panel-heading mb-3">General Information</div>
    <div class="mb-3 px-3">
      <label class="form-label fw-bold">Requesting access for:</label>
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="form-check px-4">
          <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="accessFor" formControlName="accessFor" value="Myself" /> 
          <label class="form-check-label" for="accessFor">
            Myself
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check px-4">
          <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="accessFor" formControlName="accessFor" value="Someone else" />
          <label class="form-check-label" for="accessFor">
            Someone else
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <p *ngIf="this.pressedSubmit && IdRequestForm.get('accessFor')?.errors" class="mb-3 text-danger"> Select one. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
<!--More fields... -->
</form>

Router outlet by default displays a child component called IdRequestFormComponent. This component contains html/ts code to display a Reactive form (form group, former builder, etc). I initialize this form using the class constructor. It works well overall.
My issue currently: form data within the IdRequestFormComponent isn't cleared under every circumstance where the view is navigated away from.
It currently clears if:

page is refreshed
data is properly submitted (passes validation) and then user navigates backwards

Data does not clear if:

user interacts with href link in navigation bar. Nav bar is currently written in the app root component.
In local host, if I type in any website, then navigate backwards

The worst part of is that NgIf directives in the IdRequestFormComponent HTML are not acknowledged if user enters data to trigger it true, navigates away using href, then users the browser back space. Data is still there, but ngIf evaluates to false.
Any input is welcomed, and I can provide more code/architecture description as needed. Thank you.
Tried using ngOnDestroy to call form.reset, but it did not seem to hit the breakpoint set in that function.
Also tried using canDeactivate with a custom class within the routing class, but also did not seem to see a change in behavior. It is also possible that I implemented this incorrectly:
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: IdRequestFormComponent, canDeactivate: [DeactivationGuard]},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

___________________________________

@Injectable()
export class DeactivationGuard implements CanDeactivate<any> {
  canDeactivate(component: any, currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, currentState: RouterStateSnapshot, nextState: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    const confirmation = confirm('Are you sure you wish to navigate away with unsaved data?'); // this browser confirmation never gets called!!!
    console.log("we are deactivating");
      if (confirmation) return true;
      else return false;
    }

}

As seen by the comment within the code, the browser API confirm is not called when navigating away, as it would be expected. I did make sure to add DeactivationGuard to providers within app.module.ts.

the back button behavior is just normal browser caching.  Can you include more code? Probably need to show navbar links and context of this component... is this included in another component as viewchild?  .reset() should clear the fields, so onDestroy is not happening here.

onDestroy would force you to re-initialization when component is re-loaded anyway, so if .reset() is needed it shouldn't be there.

I guess it was a mix of browser-caching + not understanding onDestroy as a lifecycle hook. From what I've understood, onDestroy would only be called when destroying a component and staying WITHIN the application (i.e. navigating to another component on another route- away from the current one).

I ended up being able to implement HostListener('window:unload') to explicitly reset this data before the user navigates away. This will attach a function to run anytime the entire application is unloaded- in this case- fully navigated away from.
@HostListener('window:unload', ['$event'])
unloadForm(): void {
this.IdRequestForm.reset();
}

onload should fire on back button as well so you can do it there instead of on unload if you like.

There is also visibilitychange event you could use if you wanted to clear when a user swtiches tabs:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilitychange_event
